# Can't connect to MySQL database (hosted in arvixe) from Cloud9 python app

Tags: python, mysql, connection, external, cpanel

I have a MySQL database hosted in "arvixe" (and managed by cPanel). I can connect to it by "MySQL Workbech" from my PC so I supose that I created it correctly.

I have a python app (a Telegram bot) hosted in Cloud9, so I use the next code to connect to the database:

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("weongame.com","weonwii_ceux","<here my pass>","weonwii_Forms_Bot")
```

The result is that, after a long time (I supose that any kind of "timeout"), the console show the next traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bot.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                                                    
    db = MySQLdb.connect("weongame.com","weonwii_ceux","<here my pass>","weonwii_Forms_Bot")                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect                                                                                                                       
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__                                                                                                                  
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)                                                                                                                                                         
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'weongame.com' (110)")
```

So I focused on the principal error: **_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'weongame.com' (110)")**

and I just found the "Remote MySQL" section on cPanel. I didn't know the exact IP I had to introduce there, so I wrote the c9.io (as host name and as IP address), the same for https://forms-bot-ceuxdruman.c9users.io (where Cloud9 says my app is running, although it is a simple script, not a webpage/webapp) and the IP address asking to the Ubuntu console of my Cloud9 workspace. But after introducing all of them (considering IPs could be dynamic), the result was exactly the same.

I also know that arvixe allow this kind of external connections, so that isn't a possible reason.

Any idea of what could be causing the error? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I used

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

to find out the real IP that was running my bot and then I included it into the "Remote MySQL" section as the others, but the result was, again, exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

- IP for Remote host. If you write host name, this hostname must be resolve to IP and mysql must be config for resolve hostname (There are different ways to configure mysql)

  - `hostname -f`
  - `host  c9.io`
- Verify on remote server that 3306 port it's open or IP of remote machine

  - `iptables -L -n |grep 3306`
  - `iptables -L -n |grep IP_remote_machine`
- If there're open firewall or not firewall, search problem on mysql. rum mysql console on mysql server (On some circunstantes Cpanel tools for Remote Access on Cpanel accounts interface fails)

Try code below ( It's possible need credentials depending on the configuration of your mysql server mysql -u root -p )

```
root@hostanme:~# mysql 
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE 'user_with_permission';
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user           | host               | password                                  |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user_perm_remo | XXX.31.31.227      | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | XX.45.170.221      | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | localhost          | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | XX.184.17.102      | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | kvm401.xxxxxxx.com | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | xxxxxxx.com        | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | %.xxxxxxx.com      | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
| user_perm_remo | xxx.33.112.218     | *3ED850F72DSHWBDS195D51D6A18EEFE0149DDA3F |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if not are a pair user/host/password for you remote connection, you get wrong privileges on your mysql server. You need add user manually.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASESNAME TO 'USERNAME'@'HOSTNAME_FDQN_OR_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If after this works no connect (also before it's a best practise) you must be check:

- test your firewall and mysql setup off remote conecctions from your machine

  telnet mysql_server 3306
- your mysql log. Read your my.conf for know where is mysql error log (usually on /var/lib/mysql/.err) and read error. If error it's for mysql problem, it's here.

NOTE: If your host has a dynamic Ip must be use % for grant remote access to dynamic IP. You can use %.%.%.% and adjust to only grant to block of possible Ip of your remote machine.